# Javascript/jquery iterate async problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, iteration, synchronous

I would like to iterate through a certain amount of pages, and populate them with content using ajax calls. The problem is, when I put the ajax calls inside the iteration function it has problems with the synchronous nature of javascript. The iteration has already continued before the ajax call is completed. So I made a workaround where I made the ajax call in a setTimeout, which works fine. But I don't really like this method, and was wondering if there is an alternative (better) solution. (I know that jQuery provides a async: true option, however that did not work)

```
function populatePages(i) {
    pageId = PageIds[i];
    containerId = pageIdContainer[i];
    $j.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html',
        url: url,
        data: { pageid: pageId, containerid: containerId },
        success: function(data) {
           //populate the DIV
        }
    });
} 


i = 0;
x = 50;
$j.each(pagesIds, function(){  
    setTimeout("populatePages("+i+")", x);
    x = x + 50;
    i++;  
});
```

Comment: what is the problem here, do you want to load the second item only after first one is completed

Comment: yes, exactly. Currently I choose a random value of 50ms that would general be sufficient, but that can fail when a request takes longer to complete. It would be much better if I can detect when exactly the ajax call is completed, before continuing the iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (not tested)

```
function populatePages(i) {
    console.log('populatePages', i)
    pageId = PageIds[i];
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html',
        url: '/echo/html',
        data: { pageid: pageId},
        success: function(data) {
        }
    });
} 


function messy(index){
    console.log('messy', index)
    if(index >= PageIds.length){
        return;
    }

    populatePages(index).always(function(){
        console.log('complete', index)
        setTimeout(function(){
            messy(index + 1)
        });//to prevent possible stackoverflow
    })
}
```

PoC: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/qcskt/)

Comment: why are you worried about a stack overflow? the function called by always will usually have a new stack anyway, you could just pass messy there.

Comment: @DavidMcMullin yes you are right, I copied it from a closure based approach

Comment: Hmm, still trying to figure it out. Currently it only calls it once, but does not reach the always callback.

"TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'populatePages(index).always')"

Comment: @user2377319 you need to add a return in `populatePages` as shown above